# Fill columns for given cells in other sheet

Tags: excel, lookup

I'm relatively new to Excel, and I'm trying to accomplish the following action:

From a database sheet (example):

[image: DB]

Given the following vector of IDs (not all may be in DB):

[image: Data]

Fill the columns for given vector of IDs (example):

[image]

Hope its clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd use Filter if you have Excel 365

Comment: VLookup, Index/Match will give you desired output.